# Is there any way to store an linked list in database in a single column such that when getting it from db it has still its nodes in it

Tags: c#, database, data-structures, linked-list, queue

Is there any way to store an linked list in database in a single column such that when getting it from db it has still its nodes in it such like the head, the tail and each node data.

Comment: You can store a serialized version of the object as json or xml or binary as long as the types involved are serializable.

Comment: You can serialize the list into your favorite format (JSON, XML etc.) and store it. Of course it's not a good idea for various reasons, so you should ask yourself if this is the best option you have.

Comment: Just turn your linked list to an array, and store the serialized array. This will take less space, and it is easy to convert an array back to a linked list once you have read it from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You must read up on "serialization" ([MS Documentation to get you started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)).

Before building decide...

(1) Whether you need to treat the whole linked list as a single object "*single column on one row*"
or
(2) Whether you can treat each entry in the list as a distinct object "*several rows, one column*"
(I strongly recommend this option because it is seldom possible to know that your design-time maximum conceivable list length and object size will not be exceeded in future.)
and
(3) What you will serialize to (binary - and presumably Base64 encoding, XML, JSON or some other custom string format).

Then you serialize either the entire list (option 1) or its contents (option 2)